# Keep Maps/Waze on screen when answering call

Tags: iphone, maps, navigation

I have my iPhone paired with my car's Bluetooth. I typically have my iPhone displaying Waze or Apple Maps in navigation mode. When I answer a call, the Phone app takes over the entire screen and I no longer see the map.

Is there anyway to keep the navigation on screen while I'm answering a phone call?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make the call screen not come up. You'll have to double-click the Home button and go back to Waze. Or, if you have an iPhone 6s/Plus, 3D touching the left side of the screen and dragging right will send you back to the previous app.

Comment: This is why I am switching back from iPhone to Android

Answer (score 0):

Only if you jailbreak your iphone and install a tweak that would allow you to do so.

Comment: That's a shame :(

Comment: whats the tweak called that allows you to do it?

Answer (score 0):

After you accept the call, just double-click the home button and get back into the navigation app. You will be able to see the map and your call won't be interrupted.

Comment: Not really an option as I am driving and don't want to have to fiddle about with my phone.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't keep it on the screen.  But you don't have to "fiddle with the phone" to bring Waze back.  Double-clicking the home button and touching the middle of the screen brings it back.

Since you can do that without looking at the phone, it is no more distracting than operating your turn signals, windshield wiper, headlights, or cruise control. If you find that distracting, then, in the interest of public safety, I would urge you to take mass transit.

Answer (score 0):

You can vote for the feature here:
https://waze.uservoice.com/forums/59223-waze-suggestion-box/suggestions/39069448-keep-waze-on-top

Hopefully, they'll work it out sooner or later if this gets enough votes.